# Ubuntu 13.10 Wifi Fail after attempting to connect to an ad-hoc network

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, network-manager

My WiFi was working for several months with the `network-manager` in Ubuntu. 
A couple of days ago, I tried to connect to an ad-hoc network. Afterwards I have not been able to connect to *any* wireless networks. I tried both `network-manager` and command line tools.

Has anyone had this problem before, and has any idea what permanent configuration changes attempting to connect to an ad hoc network might cause?

Note that `iwlist scan` works fine, and even `network-manager` can see the wireless networks. I simply cannot connect anymore, and keep getting these messages from `dmesg`:

```
[ 3084.305735] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c (try 1/3)
[ 3084.311016] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3084.311101] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3084.314983] wlan0: associate with 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c (try 1/3)
[ 3084.419117] wlan0: associate with 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c (try 2/3)
[ 3084.523236] wlan0: associate with 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c (try 3/3)
[ 3084.631359] wlan0: association with 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c timed out
[ 3084.641166] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:01:ea:e7:2c by local choice (reaso
n=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nautilus /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Then, clean out this directory (delete the profiles).

Alternatively, you could blindly clean out the directory using the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

**note: you will delete your existing wireless profiles**

Then, run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and then try to connect to your wireless network.